# After some time has passed, no ARP requests from any device get an answer over Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, arp

I've been having this problem for years but only today I finally found a track to pursue the solution.

Basically, in my house, whenever a device is connected to any of my WiFi networks, after some seemingly random interval of time has passed, the connection stops working and I need to reconnect to get it back working.

Today, while I was using my laptop, this thing happened and I immediately fired up Wireshark. The result was this:

[Wireshark Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomwG.png)

As you can see, my laptop kept sending ARPs to which it got no replies until I reconnected.

In the last few years I tried 5 different all-in-one routers but nothing changed. Right now, I have a VM on a ESXi server with pfSense as router/firewall, a separate AP from Asus and a POE injector which connects me to my provider's antenna (I think it's using WiMax but I'm not that sure). I used to have an ADSL so I don't think that's the cause.
I use WPA-2 Enterprise with a Radius server setup on a Windows Server 2016 VM on the aforementioned ESXi server for 2 of my networks, while I have 2 Guest networks with WPA2-PSK. Needless to mention, neither is immune from this ARP thing.
I have to mention that everything works just fine over Ethernet and the problem affects 2.4GHz networks as well as 5GHz. As far as I can tell, my neighbors are not experiencing any similar problem.
I tried turning both my cordless phone and microwave off but nothing changed.
This happens on every single device capable of connecting to a WiFI network.

Any idea about what might be causing this?

EDIT: here's a diagram of the network. [link to diagram](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m16i3frh3w0oozk/diagram.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: What's the make and model of the access point? What firmware is it running? And how is all this connected?

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with DHCP to me. Why in the world would your computer be running with an IP address on a /8 network? 10.x.x.x/8 tells me you have something fundamentally wrong about your network design.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think it's a DHCP problem? I am purposefully using a /8 network.
I added a diagram.

Comment: @Appleoddity While it's odd the OP chose to use a 24 bit host block with 16,777,216 hosts in one broadcast domain. it is certainly a valid private address space.

Comment: I plan on redesigning everything when I have time and money to buy some equipment, but I think that's OT. I know it's strange, as I'm always learning new things I also learn to recognise my mistakes :)

Comment: i most certainly would go with a better ip scheme then this. im running a very similar setup to you at my home. the only thing i can think is the access points, but you said you have switched them out five times. you may just want to re-build this from the ground up.

Comment: I actually have basically rebuilt everything this summer. I used to simply have a cheap TP-Link all-in-one router and some powerline running with a 192.168.0.0/24 network. And I had problems even back then. I don't know if it may be worth trying to buy some really expensive AP like something from Cisco.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I understand it is valid. But when the OP talks about multiple networks, I immediately realize this is not possible with a single /8 private network address. There has to be some overlapping address space here. Maybe the diagram will clear things up, but it’s pretty obvious this is not a functional subnet scheme. I’m not installing Dropbox to view the network diagram on my phone, which otherwise is not working, so I guess I’ve gone is far as I can go here.

Comment: @appleoddity - its entirely possible, and indeed not that uncommon in bigger orgs - you can use 10.x, 192.168.x and 172.[16-31.x] - all these ranges are RFC1918, and you can use the router to route between them.  (That said, using 10.x as a /8 is quite wasteful)

Comment: @Appleoddity I reality appreciate your comments. Yes, I have talked about multiple WiFi networks but they all refer to one actual network. I don't really see the problem with this. I think you can just download the PDF and view it offline without installing Dropbox. On an iPhone you would need to use Safari though.

Comment: I'm not trying to give you a hard time Davide. But the network diagram is very confusing. What is most confusing is why an "EOLO Box" would have a WAN port connected to your HP server, and a LAN port connected to a switch that is also connected to your HP server. The diagram is not clear on so many levels. I'm not beating you up over this, trust me, but for an expert to look at this diagram, it is unintelligible. @Davidgo - No offense, but you're missing the point. The OP mentioned multiple networks. You can't have multiple subnets on any private address block if you use a /8 subnet mask.

Comment: @Davide I know you seem to be saying you are not using multiple subnets. But, it is still unclear from your network diagram if that is truly the case. When people talk about multiple wifi networks, and your "2 networks," it immediately means to a professional that you have either multiple physically disjointed networks, or you have multiple logical subnets. In either case, that would dictate a subnet size smaller than x.255.255.255. At this point, you should understand that this problem is not an "equipment" issue as you seem to be suggesting. So, we need to understand the network to answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity I trust you when you say it's unintelligible. This was made for "internal" use by me and I only shared it because it was the only diagram I had readily available. I understand when you say that I should have my WiFi networks on separate subnets and I plan on doing that in the future. But unless you think this is strictly related to the cause of the problem, I would postpone it.

Comment: That Eolo Box was given to me by my provider. As far as I know, it's a POE injector. That diagram is wrong though, the WAN port is connected to the antenna on my roof and the LAN to the server. I'll fix the file ASAP. Sorry it was 4AM here when I was updating that diagram. I understand that you are not trying to attack me, don't worry. I appreciate your help.